# How to make a associative array from other associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm, associative-array

I need some help with another PHP problem I am working on. I won't be posting the exact question, as I'd prefer to try and apply the knowledge I get from here to solve my problem.

**First:**
I have an associative array. I must loop through the array to find the array values which have keys that begin with a specific string and push both the key and value to an output array.

*eg:*
- Loop through the below array & push all elements which have a key beginning with "edible_" to an output array:

```
$assoc_array = array(
    'edible_fruit' => 'apple',
    'animal' => 'cat',
    'edible_veg' => 'pumpkin',
    'number' => '23',
    'city' => 'Cape Town',
    'edible_berry' => 'blueberry',
    'color' => 'blue'
);
```

Would this work?

```
$result = array();

foreach ($assoc_array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 7) == "edible_") {
        array_push($result, $value);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**Second**:
How would I remove "edible_" from the output array's keys? With this second bit I have no idea where to even begin!

**Third**:
I've managed to figure out the above with all your help, thank you! Now I just need to find out how I would print each element on a new line with a date & timestamp at the end of each line? I've got this (doesn't seem to be working):

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($output)) {
    print_r("$key => $value" . date("y/m/d G.i:s", time()) . "<br>");
}
```

Comment: "Would this work?" - why not try it? It looks good to me.

Comment: To remove a string from a key, you can use `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()`. The first one will just replace anywhere in the string, the second one uses regular expressions, so you can anchor the replacement to the start of the string if you wish.

Comment: I am trying this, but it doesn't seem to print anything at all. The output remains blank :-/

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/cmOzp28p) - are you running it on the console or in Apache?

Comment: Apache.

How would I run it in console?

Comment: Depends on your operating system, but in general it's `php script.php`. On Windows it can be a bit harder since the `php` executable is often not in the system path.

Comment: Re your last edit, a small tip: we often say here that "not working" is the least helpful fault report possible, and if you can avoid the phrase entirely that may be a good thing! Instead, say what you expected to get, and what you actually got, and the results of any debugging. Could it be that `$output` should have been `$result`?

Comment: So where are we with this question? Did one answer below solved your problem?

Comment: do your solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

First of your code will work.

To remove `edible_` from the key you could use `explode()` -

```
$keyParts = explode('_', $key);
$newKey = $keyParts[1];
```

You will have to add the new keys to the array, which you're not doing now.

```
foreach ($assoc_array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 7) == "edible_") {
        $keyParts = explode('_', $key);
        $newKey = $keyParts[1];
        $result[$newKey] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

```
foreach($assoc_array as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match("/^edible_/",$key)) {
        $result[preg_replace("/^edible_/","",$key)] = $value;
    }
}
```

use `preg_match` to check if the key starts with what you are looking for and use `preg_replace` to remove the string from the beginning (`^`) of the key :)

Input (`$assoc_array`):

```
Array
(
    [edible_fruit] => apple
    [animal] => cat
    [edible_veg] => pumpkin
    [number] => 23
    [city] => Cape Town
    [edible_berry] => blueberry
    [color] => blue
)
```

Output (`$result`):

```
Array
(
    [fruit] => apple
    [veg] => pumpkin
    [berry] => blueberry
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**: yes, that would work, however I would rewrite it a bit:

```
foreach ($assoc_array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'edible_') === 0) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Regarding **Second**: You are asking how to remove the key from the output array. However you did not even push the key into the output array, you only pushed the value. If you'd like to also push the key, you should do it like this:

```
$result[$key] = $value;
```

But since you haven't done that, there's no need to remove the key.

If you however meant removing the edible_ part of the key from the `$assoc_array`, you'd just need to add a line to the loop and pass the key by reference by adding a `&`:

```
foreach ($assoc_array as &$key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'edible_') === 0) {
        $key = str_replace('edible_', '', $key)
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As OP told me in comments, she wants to push the key without the edible part. So just do it like this:

```
foreach ($assoc_array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'edible_') === 0) {
        $key = str_replace('edible_', '', $key)
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `0` for the `strpos`?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I noticed now that I didn't push the key, I was not sure how to do so. The final output would still have a key & value, but instead of being "edible_fruit" it would just be "fruit", if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and search if the key has the string that you can eliminate and make your `$newArray`

```
<?php

$assoc_array = array('edible_fruit'=>'apple', 'animal'=>'cat', 'edible_veg'=>'pumpkin', 'number'=>'23', 'city'=>'Cape Town', 'edible_berry'=>'blueberry', 'color'=>'blue');

$search = 'edible_';
$newArray = array();

#First and Second Step
foreach($assoc_array as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, "edible_") === 0) {
        $newArray[substr($key, 7)] = $value;
    }
}


print_r($newArray);

echo "<br>\n";

#Third Step
foreach($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value " . date("y/m/d G.i:s", time()) . "<br>\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
#First and Second Step
    Array ( [fruit] => apple [veg] => pumpkin [berry] => blueberry )

#Third Step    
    fruit => apple 15/04/10 3.02:16
    veg => pumpkin 15/04/10 3.02:16
    berry => blueberry 15/04/10 3.02:16
```

Comment: Whoops! Try a key of `inedible_mushroom`?

Comment: @AlliePascoal do you test my answer and you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

First I remove all elements, which doesn't have `edible_` at the start of the key with [`array_diff_ukey()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-ukey.php). After this I simply [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the elements with they keys, where I remove the prefix with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
<?php

    $assoc_array = array('edible_fruit'=>'apple', 'animal'=>'cat', 'edible_veg'=>'pumpkin', 'number'=>'23', 'city'=>'Cape Town', 'edible_berry'=>'blueberry', 'color'=>'blue');

    //remove elemnts
    $result = array_diff_ukey($assoc_array, ["edible_" => ""], function($k1, $k2){
        return substr($k1, 0, 7) == $k2;
    });

    //change keys
    $result = array_combine(
                array_map(function($v){
                    return substr($v, 7);
                }, array_keys($result)),
            $result);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [fruit] => apple [veg] => pumpkin [berry] => blueberry )
```